# How to check IS NULL on DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

In my case i am passing a sql query and getting data in dataset, but problem occurs when i try to get the rows where ParentId column contain NULL.This is the piece of code.

```
   DataSet ds = GetDataSet("Select ProductId,ProductName,ParentId from ProductTable");

   //ds is not blank and it has 2 rows in which ParentId is NULL

   DataRow[] Rows = ds.Tables[0].Select("ParentId IS NULL");
```

But still i am not getting any rows.
Need help. Thanx.

Comment: The way you're doing seems correct to me and it should be working, but make sure that it has null and not blank value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the strongly typed `DataRow` extension method [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which also supports nullable types:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => !r.Field<int?>("ParentId").HasValue);
```

Note that i've used `Enumerable.Where` which is a Linq extension method to filter the table.

If you want an array use `ToArray`, if you want a new `DataTable` use `CopyToDataTable`. If you simply want to enumerate the result use `foreach`.

```
foreach(DataRow row in rows)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: still it is showing this- base {System.SystemException} = {"Specified cast is not valid."} . when i write string instead of int it shows- {The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>} .i am not familier with linq.

Comment: @Anand; Then the type of the `DataColumn` is `string` instead of `int`(as i've presumed). You have to use `.Where(r => r.Field<string>("ParentId")==null)` instead.

Comment: now it is showing- {Empty = "Enumeration yielded no results"}...why so ? :(

Comment: @Anand: Because there are no rows with ParentId=null?! Can you show the last query you have tried?

Comment: DataSet ds = GetDataSet("Select ProductId,ProductName,ParentId from ProductTable");
IEnumerable<DataRow> Rows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("ParentId")==null); there is no code between these two lines and believe me data set contain 10 rows and two of them has null in parentid column. even i don't know what the problem is, tired of doing this.

Comment: finally it is done..it is working as ("ParentId")=="NULL") instead of ("ParentId")==null)..Happy ending finally :)

Comment: @Anand: Then the `ParentId` is not `null` or `DbNull.Value` but simply a string "NULL".

Comment: can you help me with this-     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631203/how-to-create-a-simple-diagram-in-c-net

Answer (score 5):

```
var rowsWithoutParent = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["ParentId"] == null);

var rowsWithParent = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["ParentId"] != null);
```

Comment: it is counting all the rows, how to count only null

Comment: This answer guide me to check if a column value is empty when reading from a csv file. For me it was like - `data.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["SHORT_CODE"].ToString() == "").Any();`

Answer (score 3):

```
var rows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.IsNull("ParentId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

work for me:

```
   DataTable newDt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["column name"] == DBNull.Value).CopyToDataTable();
```

if equal to `null` is not work because is return `DBNull`

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, a good answer should always contain an explanation of the code.

Answer (score -1):

Check

```
ds.Tables.Count
```

then

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access the items like this:

```
 String value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[RowNum][ColNum].ToString();
```