# How to prevent error conversion from DBNull value to Decimal in Linq query results

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to sum numeric values from a datatable using linq but because there are also null values in column `UniteDispo` I am getting an error:

> Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'Decimal'. Please use a nullable type.

This is my code:

```
Dim query2 = (From order In tabDispoAnnee.AsEnumerable() _
    Where order.Field(Of Integer)("code_part") = tab.Rows(i).Item("code_part") And order.Field(Of Integer)("CodeTypeBien") = tab.Rows(i).Item("CodeTypeBien") _
    Group order By order!code_part, order!CodeTypeBien _
    Into unit = Sum(CDec(order("UniteDispo"))), ca = Sum(CDec(order("CADispo"))) _
    Select unit, ca).ToList
```

What is the proper syntax to overcome this error?

Comment: Add a `Where` clause to filter out records with *`NULL`* value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Where` clause to filter out records with *`NULL`* value. Try this

```
Dim query2 = (From order In tabDispoAnnee.AsEnumerable() _
    Where order.Field(Of Integer)("code_part") = tab.Rows(i).Item("code_part") _ 
    And order.Field(Of Integer)("CodeTypeBien") = tab.Rows(i).Item("CodeTypeBien") _
    And order.Field(Of Integer?)("UniteDispo").HasValue _
    And order.Field(Of Double?)("CADispo").HasValue _
    Group order By order!code_part, order!CodeTypeBien _
    Into unit = Sum(CDec(order("UniteDispo"))), ca = Sum(CDec(order("CADispo"))) _
    Select unit, ca).ToList
```

Comment: It that's not work i have this error : "'IsNot' Requires operands that have reference types but this operand has the value type'Decimal'"

Comment: unfortunately i have this error "The specified cast is invalid"

Comment: Are you sure it's stored in the database as `Decimal` with *`NULL`*? Or maybe it's text?

Comment: yes in datatbase "UniteDispo" is declared int and "CADispo" is declared float and bot have some value are Null,of corse i have chage    And order.Field(Of Integer?)("UniteDispo").HasValue

Comment: It should then be `order.Field(Of Integer?)("UniteDispo").HasValue` and `order.Field(Of Single?)("CADispo").HasValue`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15523970/832052. According to that post the OP has an issue in an assumption that the value is not a string, while it was a string. He was checking for Nullable (as I suggested, according to your information), but he needed to check for string *`"NULL"`*. Try both

Comment: Thanks "djv" it's work just i change the type Decimal to Double in < And order.Field(Of Double?)("UniteDispo").HasValue _>